# Why will my logo not adjust when window is resized?

Tags: responsive-design

I used a free Responsive Template offered by http://www.Sg-layout.com.  It looks great and I'm finishing up however I noticed the logo will not adjust center when I resize the page past 776x796 .  It stays left I have tried changing the width to 100% but thats not what I'm looking to accomplish.  I would like to keep the current position just have the logo adjust when page is resized.  Here is my site http://www.newmeccarecords.com

Answer (score 0):

While this won't work for older browsers, this will do the trick:

```
@media (max-width: 720px) { 
  #logo {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

This will force the width only when the browser is smaller.

Details on which browsers support it: http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/@media_(max-width)

For those that it doesn't support, it just stays on the left, which to be honest doesn't look that bad. (plus they should upgrade anyways.)

Comment: Works thank you however I now have a small white space about 1/8 on the right side of my page when the screen goes past the break point

Comment: Strangely, I'm not seeing that phenomena on my Chrome browser. So I cannot help much.

Comment: I understand you did say it would not work in all browsers.  I'm using updated version of Firefox with firebug.  I see it on the iPhone in safari.  I also tried to give it a negative margin with no luck.

Comment: Can you post a Screenshot for review?

Comment: Click the link for the screenshot in last comment

Comment: Just tested on my iPhone 4 with Safari and Chrome, it is fine.

Comment: My guess is it's a bug with the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Just define in your media queries

```
@media screen (min-width:320px) and (max-width:776px){
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

It assumes that `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` It'll follow the window resize auto margins and always be in the middle of the page.